# Issues with files loading based on path

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I'm using rails 2, and in one of the plugin I'm working on, I found this weird issue, I've TinyMce 4 customized text editor.

I've loaded the script at the beginning of the page, in the **new** form.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

TinyMce loads normally, and works completely fine.

---

In case of **edit** form the same script tag above doesn't work, I've move up 1 level to load it, I mean

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Out of curiosity, what is going on here?

Folder Sturucture.

>>plugin_name
  >>app
  >>config
  >>db
  >>lib
  >>public
    >>images
    >>javascripts
    >>stylesheets
    >>**tinymce**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your new page has a url like : `/post/new` whereas your edit page has a url like `/post/1/edit`

Because the edit URL has an extra `/` you need to go up an extra level in the relative path in your script tag.

Try changing the TinyMCE include to be an absolute path, not a relative one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```