# Responsive filemanager in tinymce, directory settings

Tags: directory, tinymce, tinymce-4, file-manager, responsive-filemanager

I'm using this file manager for file upload in tinymce.
[**File Manager**](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/)

Having some problem with the directory. I'm using tinymce 4.

My filemanager folder is in "**localhost/BAD/**" directory,
I have a file named about.php which is in "**localhost/BAD/admin/**" directory. Now I can upload image and see from that about.php file. My settings of tinymce is

```
**external_filemanager_path:"/BAD/filemanager/",
filemanager_title:"Filemanager" ,
external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "filemanager/plugin.min.js"}**
```

And my cofig.php file settings are

```
$base_url="http://localhost"; 
$upload_dir = '/BAD/source/'; 
$current_path = '../source/'; 
$thumbs_base_path = '../thumbs/';
```

After uploading image and selecting,it shows a path in the image source box as "**../source/eng.jpg**" and saved that into database.

But I want to access this image from **"localhost/BAD/" directory NOT "localhost/BAD/admin/"**. It starts to find the source file on 'localhost', Not in '**localhost/BAD**'

I tried some changes but not working. How can I save the source link as "source/eng.jpg" instead of  "../source/eng.jpg" or is there any way to save the image from one directory and access it from previous level directory?

Comment: I had same issue, check this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912088/script-loading-issue

Comment: @Nithin I was having problem with a third party plugin (Responsive filemanager), not directly with TinyMCE. Thanks for your comment :) I solved it already

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

In tinymce init:

```
relative_urls:false,
external_filemanager_path:"/BAD/filemanager/",
filemanager_title:"Filemanager" ,
external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/BAD/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
```

and in config.php

```
$base_url="http://localhost"; 
$upload_dir = '/BAD/source/'; 
$current_path = '../source/'; 
$thumbs_base_path = '../thumbs/';
```