# Cannot integrate File responsive manager with TinyMCE 4

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to integrate the file manager [Responsive File Manager](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/) into TinyMCE.  I've followed the installation steps it lists for TinyMCE however when I try to insert a file I get a blank screen.

Not quite sure where I'm going wrong so any help would be much appreciated.  My code is below:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"  Inherits="_Default" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce_4.0.16/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js">               </script>

<!--TinyMCE 4 -->
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea#elm1",
            theme: "modern",
            width: 1000,
            height: 1000,
            plugins: [
                 "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                 "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                 "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor responsivefilemanager"
            ],
            content_css: "css/content.css",
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ink image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons | responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | print preview code ",

            image_advtab: true,
            relative_urls: false,

            external_filemanager_path: "file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202012/Projects/TinyMCE/ResponsiveFilemanagerMaster/filemanager/",
            filemanager_title: "Responsive File Manager",
            external_plugin: { "filemanager": "file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202012/Projects/TinyMCE/ResponsiveFilemanagerMaster/filemanager/plugin.min.js" },

            style_formats: [
                 { title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b' },
                 { title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: { color: '#ff0000' } },
                 { title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: { color: '#ff0000' } },
                 { title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1' },
                 { title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2' },
                 { title: 'Table styles' },
                 { title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1' }
            ]
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="Default.aspx">
    <div>
    <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%"></textarea>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to assist others that may run into this problem, I should note that the documentation on the Responsive File Manager fails to share one important step.

In the zipped file there is a **filemanager** folder and a **tinymce** folder.

Documentation on mentions copying the **filemanager** folder (preferably to your root web folder).

But does not say anything about the plugin folder thats in the **tinymce** folder.

Copy

```
tinymce/plugins/responsivefilemanager
```

folder from the zipped download to your

```
tinymce/plugins
```

on your webserver.

Keep in mind that the **responsivefilemanager** folder is different than the main **filemanager** folder. In your init for tinyMCE, you want to point the *external_filemanager_path* to the main **filemanager** folder. Same with the *plugin.min.js*

Answer (score 0):

Put the `filemanager` folder in your project folder

```
relative_urls:false,
image_advtab: true ,
external_filemanager_path:"/yourprojectname/filemanager/",
filemanager_title:"Filemanager" ,
external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The file manager folder was already in my project folder within ResponsiveFilemanagerMaster.  I took it out and pasted it in the root of the project and I still have the same issue.

Comment: see if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627785/responsive-filemanager-in-tinymce-directory-settings Though I was using it in php projects not .NET, but I think the approach shold be similar @C0pperBeard

Comment: I gave up in the end with Responsive File Manager, couldn't seem to find a solution.  I ended up finding another file manager [.NET File Manager](http://www.andyarndt.net/TinyFileManager.aspx#sthash.mgJmiWxg.dpbs) and managed to integrate that instead.